# NodeJS v3 GetObject's .Body attribute doesn't include data buffer

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I expect a buffer of bytes or blob for the .Body attribute on the response object. But no buffer. Same API works in v2.

```
let params: GetObjectRequest = {
     Bucket: "my-bucket",
     Key: file,
  };

const command = new GetObjectCommand(params);
client.send(command).then((obj: GetObjectCommandOutput) => {
  console.log(obj);   // obj.Body is IncomingMessage type, looks like a req/res object, see below
});
```

console.log(obj) output: (where's the byte stream buffer?)

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: 'x7A0J21CrOpeQ7O5I3LGtbH4yQcFPQmmnVSHbBDHy7iSImMfyXephea10B0jn0vz6NA03mzgWAs=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  Body: <ref *1> IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: responseOnEnd] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 318,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: false,
    headers: {
      'x-amz-id-2': 'x7A0J21CrOpeQ7O5I3LGtbH4yQcFPQmmnVSHbBDHy7iSImMfyXephea10B0jn0vz6NA03mzgWAs=',
      'x-amz-request-id': 'PYBCZW7TDH874YEW',
      date: 'Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:04 GMT',
      'last-modified': 'Mon, 10 May 2021 03:22:00 GMT',
      etag: '"5ca793adbf0016a9e61ba83c48049000"',
      'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
      'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
      server: 'AmazonS3',
      'content-length': '519667'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'x-amz-id-2',
      'x7A0J21CrOpeQ7O5I3LGtbH4yQcFPQmmnVSHbBDHy7iSImMfyXephea10B0jn0vz6NA03mzgWAs=',
      'x-amz-request-id',
      'PYBCZW7TDH874YEW',
      'Date',
      'Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:04 GMT',
      'Last-Modified',
      'Mon, 10 May 2021 03:22:00 GMT',
      'ETag',
      '"5ca793adbf0016a9e61ba83c48049000"',
      'Accept-Ranges',
      'bytes',
      'Content-Type',
      'image/jpeg',
      'Server',
      'AmazonS3',
      'Content-Length',
      '519667'
    ],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '',
    method: null,
    statusCode: 200,
    statusMessage: 'OK',
    client: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 318,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    req: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /2010/01/Just-because-youre-careful.jpg?x-id=GetObject HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'host: ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r\n' +
        'x-amz-user-agent: aws-sdk-js/3.18.0\r\n' +
        'user-agent: aws-sdk-js/3.18.0 os/darwin/20.4.0 lang/js md/nodejs/14.15.4 api/s3/3.18.0\r\n' +
        'amz-sdk-invocation-id: 1a8ef70a-da2c-4776-8a96-0229005a7d66\r\n' +
        'amz-sdk-request: attempt=1; max=3\r\n' +
        'x-amz-date: 20210607T225203Z\r\n' +
        'x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\r\n' +
        'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIATBG74RDTF373ZWHS/20210607/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=8dccaec651cd083d361f0a08e9d10f9ef042d13d9981b8147a98300e8be57a59\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/2010/01/Just-because-youre-careful.jpg?x-id=GetObject',
      _ended: false,
      res: [Circular *1],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  BucketKeyEnabled: undefined,
  CacheControl: undefined,
  ContentDisposition: undefined,
  ContentEncoding: undefined,
  ContentLanguage: undefined,
  ContentLength: 519667,
  ContentRange: undefined,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  DeleteMarker: undefined,
  ETag: '"5ca793adbf0016a9e61ba83c48049000"',
  Expiration: undefined,
  Expires: undefined,
  LastModified: 2021-05-10T03:22:00.000Z,
  Metadata: {},
  MissingMeta: undefined,
  ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus: undefined,
  ObjectLockMode: undefined,
  ObjectLockRetainUntilDate: undefined,
  PartsCount: undefined,
  ReplicationStatus: undefined,
  RequestCharged: undefined,
  Restore: undefined,
  SSECustomerAlgorithm: undefined,
  SSECustomerKeyMD5: undefined,
  SSEKMSKeyId: undefined,
  ServerSideEncryption: undefined,
  StorageClass: undefined,
  TagCount: undefined,
  VersionId: undefined,
  WebsiteRedirectLocation: undefined
}
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: undefined,
    extendedRequestId: 'Co820ZtW7f0fCWmUvh8Z+Ra04MDjAWHJkNaAAB89UVU4tPgnjbC+F/wbErDiLtsIOK8pvbSAba8=',
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  Body: <ref *1> IncomingMessage {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: false,
      highWaterMark: 16384,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [],
      flowing: null,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: false,
      sync: true,
      needReadable: false,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: false,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: false,
      destroyed: false,
      errored: null,
      closed: false,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: true,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { end: [Function: responseOnEnd] },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 463,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    httpVersionMajor: 1,
    httpVersionMinor: 1,
    httpVersion: '1.1',
    complete: false,
    headers: {
      'x-amz-id-2': 'Co820ZtW7f0fCWmUvh8Z+Ra04MDjAWHJkNaAAB89UVU4tPgnjbC+F/wbErDiLtsIOK8pvbSAba8=',
      'x-amz-request-id': 'PYB05QWDNWTXGF3R',
      date: 'Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:04 GMT',
      'last-modified': 'Mon, 10 May 2021 03:22:01 GMT',
      etag: '"bebd503437994699ece80a1dffd0d031"',
      'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
      'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
      'content-length': '227789',
      server: 'AmazonS3'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'x-amz-id-2',
      'Co820ZtW7f0fCWmUvh8Z+Ra04MDjAWHJkNaAAB89UVU4tPgnjbC+F/wbErDiLtsIOK8pvbSAba8=',
      'x-amz-request-id',
      'PYB05QWDNWTXGF3R',
      'Date',
      'Mon, 07 Jun 2021 22:52:04 GMT',
      'Last-Modified',
      'Mon, 10 May 2021 03:22:01 GMT',
      'ETag',
      '"bebd503437994699ece80a1dffd0d031"',
      'Accept-Ranges',
      'bytes',
      'Content-Type',
      'image/jpeg',
      'Content-Length',
      '227789',
      'Server',
      'AmazonS3'
    ],
    trailers: {},
    rawTrailers: [],
    aborted: false,
    upgrade: false,
    url: '',
    method: null,
    statusCode: 200,
    statusMessage: 'OK',
    client: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 11,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      _httpMessage: [ClientRequest],
      timeout: 0,
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 463,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _consuming: false,
    _dumped: false,
    req: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'GET /2011/06/Untitled-hogg-2.jpg?x-id=GetObject HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'host: ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\r\n' +
        'x-amz-user-agent: aws-sdk-js/3.18.0\r\n' +
        'user-agent: aws-sdk-js/3.18.0 os/darwin/20.4.0 lang/js md/nodejs/14.15.4 api/s3/3.18.0\r\n' +
        'amz-sdk-invocation-id: 3b5ddcd7-089c-4680-b98b-14563e5bf5a8\r\n' +
        'amz-sdk-request: attempt=1; max=3\r\n' +
        'x-amz-date: 20210607T225203Z\r\n' +
        'x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\r\n' +
        'authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIATBG74RDTF373ZWHS/20210607/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-user-agent, Signature=45c1e7f1e4e6df578c833ca8fde8d6b73fec39ba517a23d6e30e0d345e74b51e\r\n' +
        'Connection: keep-alive\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/2011/06/Untitled-hogg-2.jpg?x-id=GetObject',
      _ended: false,
      res: [Circular *1],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: [Function: emitRequestTimeout],
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: [HTTPParser],
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'ae-art.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
  },
  BucketKeyEnabled: undefined,
  CacheControl: undefined,
  ContentDisposition: undefined,
  ContentEncoding: undefined,
  ContentLanguage: undefined,
  ContentLength: 227789,
  ContentRange: undefined,
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  DeleteMarker: undefined,
  ETag: '"bebd503437994699ece80a1dffd0d031"',
  Expiration: undefined,
  Expires: undefined,
  LastModified: 2021-05-10T03:22:01.000Z,
  Metadata: {},
  MissingMeta: undefined,
  ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus: undefined,
  ObjectLockMode: undefined,
  ObjectLockRetainUntilDate: undefined,
  PartsCount: undefined,
  ReplicationStatus: undefined,
  RequestCharged: undefined,
  Restore: undefined,
  SSECustomerAlgorithm: undefined,
  SSECustomerKeyMD5: undefined,
  SSEKMSKeyId: undefined,
  ServerSideEncryption: undefined,
  StorageClass: undefined,
  TagCount: undefined,
  VersionId: undefined,
  WebsiteRedirectLocation: undefined
}
```

Answer (score -1):

"The new APIs are returning Node streams. So you need to read the streams using the stream interfaces. In my case I am just going to use the get-stream npm package to read into a Buffer."

see more at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/1096